# Discontinued numbering of list items

Tags: support, markdown

I want to format a list with a few paragraphs between items. Unfortunately, the numbering gets restarted. I want:

```
 1. item1

Paragraph1...

<!-- language: lang-java -->

    Object o = new Object();

 2. item2
```

Here's how it comes out:

1. item1

Paragraph1...

```java
Object o = new Object();
```

2. item2

Not only numbering is lost, but also indentation. I know that HTML `<ol></ol>` to which this is formatted is not supposed for big list items, but I can't see any other way to do it, except with putting the HTML tags myself. The numbering is OK, but this destroys formatting completely:

1. item1
  Paragraph1...

  Object o = new Object();
2. item2

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to insert a space before `Paragraph1...`

1. item1

   Paragraph1...

   ```java
   Object o = new Object();
   ```
2. item2

---

The code I'm using is a follows;

```
 1. item1

 Paragraph1...

    <!-- language: lang-java -->

        Object o = new Object();

 2. item2
```

---

There's also not normally a need to set the language you're using (does SO even use this?):

```
 1. item1

 Paragraph1...

        Object o = new Object();

 2. item2
```

Gives:

1. item1

   Paragraph1...

   ```
   Object o = new Object();
   ```
2. item2

Comment: ... and indent code 8 spaces instead of 4. OK, got it. Not that it's very intuitive... Thanks!

Comment: @MaDa: The space before the paragraph tells the parser you want it to be part of the list... otherwise you've got no way to detect whether you wanted it to be part of the list, or a paragraph between 2 lists. I'm not sure why you have to indent *another* 4 spaces rather than 1 for the code-in-a-list, but it's removes any confusion again.